# Unable to reload UIWebView to a new URL via code

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

Am loading a URL on a UIWebView at the viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL      
   URLWithString:@"http://abc.com/Test.html"]]];
}
```

Then on an NSTimer I run a the following to execute the javascript. The call to the JavaScript works well.

```
-(void)WebViewLoad:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{

    NSString *abcFiles  = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"abc.length"];
    NSLog(@"The TotalNumberOfFiles is %i",abcFiles); //This works
//--------------------------------------------------------
    NSString *currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"Current url 1 is %@",currentURL);

   [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.com/newpage.html"]]];
   [self.view addSubview:webView];


   NSString *currentURL2 = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
   NSLog(@"Current url 2 is %@",currentURL2);
}
```

Everything above the commented line works. 
But the part where the new URL is added, I still get the initial URL.
I tried adding reload. It did not work.
Tried creating a new UIWebView object that too did not work.

Result is

```
Current url 1 is http: //abc.com/Test.html 
Current url 2 is http: //abc.com/Test.html
```

I want

```
Current url 1 is http: //abc.com/Test.html
Current url 2 is http: //abc.com/newpage.html
```

Another question is that "can we load a new URL from the code. Its not coming via a button or any action. Its coming from a recurring timer. Is that an issue?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the request you expect is that the `request` property of `UIWebView` is not changed by `loadRequest:` until *after* the request has been fully loaded, including all redirects and assets.

Comment: You are right. I realized that if I try to load pages one after the other they are not loaded. So I changed it to keep polling till the first page finishes loading and then make a call again. Thanks a lot